# How can intercept the requests in the x-ms-webview?

Tags: cordova, winjs, win-universal-app

I want intercept the request to Images, JS, fonts, etc when load the url and use the local resources. It is possible to do on Windows?

Android you can use shouldinterceptrequest. I need something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on Windows 8.1 apps. It is only possible on Windows 10 apps.

Comment: How does it on Win 10 Apps?

Comment: I am also interested in how I can reach local resources from x-ms-webview. Thanks in advance!